# Erase everything but last X entries from an SQL table?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there an MySQL query which would delete all values from a table, except the latest 20 entries (ordered by `id`)?

So let's say I have a table `notifications`, where 1000 notifications reside and I want to keep only latest 20.

If SQL is not enough for this, using `php` is optional.

I have a few ideas how to do this, but I don't really consider them efficient.

Comment: By SQL, I assume you need a mysql compliant query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the latest id, store it into local variable and then delete everything below this id:

```
set @tmp_id := (select id from notifications order by id desc limit 20,1);
delete from notifications where id <= @tmp_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not ran this, so I apologize if it doesn't work, but according to the SQL syntax for delete this *should* work.

<strike>DELETE FROM notifications ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notifications)-20);</strike>

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT ids FROM notifications");
$count = $result->num_rows;
$count -=20;
$result = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM notifications ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $count");
```

Comment: I think it won't, because you can't use subselect to the same table while deleting.

Comment: good point, I would probably have to break this up into two statements and use php to store the result of the count.